# Looking for a PDF eBook hosting solution for intranet site

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, open-source, intranet, web-application

I'm a Ubuntu user who has a number of books on my computer in PDF format. I'm looking for a solution for hosting these books on my home intranet site. I want to make them searchable over the web, display snippets in the search results, allow users to download the files if they like, upload new ones, access them though the intranet using mobile devices, etc. Are there any solutions out there for this? I like open source software best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [**Calibre**](http://calibre-ebook.com/). Calibre is classified as e-book management software and is perfect for a collection like yours. Calibre has a built in web-server which they call the [**content server**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibre_(software)#Content_server), which would allow you to access your connection over an intranet and (optionally) the internet.

[image]

Calibre is FOSS.

Comment: Curses, you beat me (by 20 minutes). :)